# Resolve Ambiguity in Interface based approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I tried below Repository Pattern implementation

```
interface IRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> All { get; }
    T Find(object id);
    void Insert(T model); 
}
```

Then i have IAdminRepository defined below

```
interface IAdminRepository : IRpository<Role>, IRepository<User>
{
}

public class AdminRepository:IAdminRepository
{
    IQueryable<User> IRepository<User>.All
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    User IRepository<User>.Find(object id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IRepository<User>.Insert(User model)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IQueryable<Role> IRepository<Role>.All
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    Role IRepository<Role>.Find(object id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IRepository<Role>.Insert(Role model)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In my business layer i use Interface based calling.

```
public interface IAdminService
{
    bool CreateUser(User user);        
    List<User> GetAllUsers();
}

public class AdminService : IAdminService
{
    private readonly IAdminRepository AdminRepository;

    public AdminService(IAdminRepository _adminRepository)
    {
        AdminRepository = _adminRepository;
    }

    public bool CreateUser(User user)
    {
        AdminRepository.Insert(user);
        return true;
    }

    public List<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return AdminRepository.All; // Here is error 
    }
}
```

> Error: Ambiguity between IRepository.All &
>   IRepository.All.

How to resolve this? What is the problem with my approach of using Repository Pattern in this way?

Comment: your IAdminRepository inherits from IRepository<Role> an IRepository<User>, so when you do AdminRepository.All, it doesn't know  which .All to be called, as it has both for User and Role. What you should do is to Make your IAdminRepository of Type T and inherit IRepository<T>

Comment: @ManishMishra, Do you say AdminRepository<Admin> ? Its not at all meaningful here :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this line

```
return AdminRepository.All; // Here is error
```

should be

```
return ((IRepository<User>)AdminRepository).All.ToList();
```

You probably noticed that you would not have been able to declare `.All` without explicitly writing which interface you were implementing. That's because, for a given class, two properties with the same name can not have different return types.

It is the same when invoking. You have to tell exactly which property you are invoking. This is done by casting the object to the desired interface.

Anyway, it seems you will end-up implementing the repositories for all of your entity types. You should just implement `IRepository<T>` once for entity types which can be retrieved from the same mechanism.

If you want your repository to apply only on some classes, you may, for example, tag these classes with an interface. Let's say `IEntity`.

```
public interface IEntity
{
}
```

then

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T:IEntity
{
    IQueryable<T> All { get; }
    T Find(object id);
    void Insert(T model);
}
```

You can even have db repositories which only apply to entities you would have tagged as being db entities, like this :

```
public interface IDbEntity: IEntity
{
}


public class DbRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T:IDbEntity
{
    public IQueryable<T> All { get; private set; }
    public T Find(object id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(T model)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good guess, but missing an explanation *Why*.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to disambiguate the call is to create aliasing methods:

```
public class AdminRepository : IAdminRepository {

  public IQueryable<User> AllUsers {
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  }

  public IQueryable<Role> AllRoles {
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  }

  IQueryable<User> IRepository<User>.All {
    get { return AllUsers; }
  }

  IQueryable<Role> IRepository<Role>.All {
    get { return AllRoles; }
  }

  ...
}
```